# Elegant way to map events with 2 parameters to specific methods

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a game in Unity and I have multiple objects (apple, orange, banana, etc) that can collide with multiple collider objects (net, box, hoop, etc).  Each match has specific functionality.
Assuming there is 10 objects and 10 collider objects, that is 100 methods.
I'd like to avoid switch/if-else statements if possible.

Currently, the collision is triggered on the collider object, then I send it to a dispatch:

```
public class NetCollision : BaseCollider {
CollisionDispatch dispatch;

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision coll)
{
    Fruit obj = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Fruit> ();
    dispatch.RegisterCollision (obj, this, coll);
}}
```

In CollisionDispatch, I have switch statements like so:

```
    public void RegisterCollision(Fruit obj, BaseCollider collider, Collision collision) {
    if (obj is Banana) {
        BananaDispatch (obj as Banana, collider, collision)
    } else if (obj is Apple) {
        AppleDispatch (obj as Banana, collider, collision)
    } ...
}

public void BananaDispatch (Banana obj, BaseCollider coll, Collision collision) {
    if (coll is NetCollider) {
    // Banana-NetCollider method
    } else if (coll is BoxCollider) {
    // Banana-BoxCollider method
    } ...
}
```

Is this a situation to use generics?  I've tried refactoring for generics, but it doesn't seem to clean up the code.

Comment: A simple way would be to keep a `Dictionary<Type, Action<Parameter>>` and pass the parameters on based on the object type.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks, I did consider this.  However, I would need a two key dictionary, as there is both a fruit and a collider which decide which function to call.  I think I decided against it as the functions have to be defined somewhere, and the dictionary seemed superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use polymorphism and strategy or state pattern.
For example:

```
public class CollisionDispatch : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void RegisterCollision(Fruit obj, BaseCollider collider, Collision collision)
    {
        obj.Dispatch(collider, collision);
    }
}

public interface ICollisionableFruit
{
    //add method for each collision type
    void HandleNetCollision(Collision collision);
    void HandleElseCollision(Collision collision);
}

public abstract class Fruit : ICollisionableFruit
{
    public virtual void Dispatch(BaseCollider collider, Collision collision)
    {
        collider.HandleCollision(this, collision);
    }

    //declare all of interface's methods as abstract
    public abstract void HandleNetCollision(Collision collision);
    public abstract void HandleElseCollision(Collision collision);
}


public class Banana : Fruit
{
    //override all methods
    public override void HandleNetCollision(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("HandleNetCollision for {0}", this.GetType());
    }

    public override void HandleElseCollision(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("HandleElseCollision for {0}", this.GetType());
    }
}

public abstract class BaseCollider
{
    CollisionDispatch dispatch;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
    {
        var obj = coll.gameObject.GetComponent<Fruit>();
        dispatch.RegisterCollision(obj, this, coll);
    }

    public abstract void HandleCollision(ICollisionableFruit fruit, Collision collision);
}

public class NetCollision : BaseCollider
{
    public override void HandleCollision(ICollisionableFruit fruit, Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("NetCollision HandleCollision");
        fruit.HandleNetCollision(collision);
    }
}

public class ElseCollision : BaseCollider
{
    public override void HandleCollision(ICollisionableFruit fruit, Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("NetCollision HandleCollision");
        fruit.HandleElseCollision(collision);
    }
}
```

You will just override `Dispatch` method for all inherites from `Fruit`, and `HandleCollision` for all inherites from `BaseCollider`. Also you can add abstract specific method to Fruit for each `BaseCollider` inherites and call it from `HandleCollision` if it implies different collision handling dependent fruit type.

If you need to use more colliders just you will need to add new method to `ICollisionableFruit`, `Fruit`, and each inherites.

It is not clearly flexible solution, but its better than hundreed of `if`.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, I can only implement one function override for HandleCollision<TFruit>, but I need 10 functions, one for each fruit.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you have a bunch of `Fruit` objects that all have to react differently when a particular object of type `FruitObstacle` collides with them.

For this I would use inheritance:

- Create a base class `Fruit` which will have the `OnCollisionEnter` method.
- Create all the `CollideWithNet`, `CollideWithBox`... as `abstract` methods.
- Run a `switch` in the `OnCollisionEnter` method to detect what was the type of the colliding object (there are many way to detect that, you could use `tags` on the `FruitObstacle` for example) and call the corresponding method.
- Create all your fruit child inheriting the `Fruit` class (`Banana : Fruit`, `Apple : Fruit`...).
- Implement the custom logic for each of your `CollideWithBox`, `CollideWithNet`... methods for each of the fruits.

If you have some logic that is always the same for every fruit you can use `virtual` methods instead of `abstract` methods and add the logic in the `Fruit` class (don't forget to call the base class in your inherited class with `base.MethodName`).

Comment: Thanks for the input.  That might be the best way, but I was trying to avoid switch statements and have it all run dynamically.  Unfortunately, a GetComponent<BaseFruitObstacle> returns the base class, and if you pass it to an overloaded method with the correct derived class, it still registers as the base.  So in the end, this may be the only way

Comment: I don't think you can avoid a switch here, if all the combination Fruit-Obstacle have different result you will need a switch. I'm not sure what you mean for the rest, GetComponent returns the class you ask for, if you ask for Fruit it will return a Fruit, if you ask for a Banana it will return a Banana (assuming the object does have the Banana or Fruit Script).

Comment: In the OnCollisionEnter function, I retrieve the fruit object with a GetComponent<BaseFruit>, because I don't know which fruit it is.  This is the crux of my problem, as I then have to type check it in a switch statement.  In a perfect world, I could pass the result of GetComponent<BaseFruit> to a bunch of function overrides that take the derived fruit classes, and the runtime would decide which is the proper function.  I suppose we can't do this because there isn't a guarantee that every fruit will be accounted for as a function override?

Comment: I can't think of any way to determine what the Fruit is without doing a type check. I don't think it's a bad thing either, if your objects have different behaviour it make sense to check what the object is to apply the right behaviour.